# Connection with multiple users using singleton pattern pdo connection

Tags: php, pdo, singleton

1. I have a database with 5 users like hr, pay ,misc. I am using singleton database pattern to connect and execute query to these database users.
2. I am accessing connection information from Config Class, where i am storing connection parameters as an array.
3. I want to get a new connection object when i change parameter in getInstance method for example 
    $data1 = DB::getInsatance('common')->query("select * from Table1 (in common)"); 
    $data2 = DB::getInsatance('misc')->query("select * from Table2 (in misc) ");

   But whenever two instance methods are created with seperate users,the object initiated later in the flow is not generated

```html
<!--
This is my DB class where my pdo parameters will change based on arguement supplied in getInstance() method  --->




<?php
include_once 'Config.php';
class DB {
 private static $_instance = null;
 private $_pdo, $_query, $_error = false, $_results, $_count = 0;
 protected $user;
 private function __construct($user) {
 try {
   $this -> _pdo = new PDO('oci:dbname=//' . Config::get($user.'/host') . '/' . Config::get($user.'/db'), Config::get($user.'/username'), Config::get($user.'/password'));

  } catch (PDOException $e) {
   die($e -> getMessage());
  }
  
  
 }

 public static function getInstance($user) {
  
  if (!isset(self::$_instance)) {
   self::$_instance = new DB($user);
  }
  //return $user;
  return self::$_instance;
 }

 public function query($sql, $params = array()) {
  //echo $sql.'<br>';
  $this -> _error = false;
  if ($this -> _query = $this -> _pdo -> prepare($sql)) {
   $x = 1;
   if (count($params)) {
    foreach ($params as $param) {
     $this -> _query -> bindValue($x, $param);
     $x++;
    }
   }

   if ($this -> _query -> execute()) {
    $this -> _results = $this -> _query -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    foreach ($this ->_results as $result) {
     $this -> _count++;

    }
    //return $this ->_count;
   } else {
    $this -> _error = true;
   }
  }
  return $this;
 }

 public function action($action, $table, $where = array()) {
  if (count($where) === 3) {
   $operators = array('=', '>', '<', '>=', '<=','like');

   $field = $where[0];
   $operator = $where[1];
   $value = $where[2];

   if (in_array($operator, $operators)) {
    $sql = "{$action} FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} {$operator} ?";

    if (!$this -> query($sql, array($value)) -> error()) {
     return $this;
    }
   }
  }
  return false;
 }

 public function get($table, $where) {
  return $this -> action('SELECT *', $table, $where);
 }

 public function delete($table, $where) {
  return $this -> action('DELETE', $table, $where);
 }

 public function getf($keys = array(), $table, $wheres = array(array(),array(),array())) {

  $fields = $wheres[0];
  $qoperator = $wheres[1];
  $values = $wheres[2];
  $operators = array('=', '>', '<', '>=', '<=');
  foreach ($fields as $field) {
   $this -> field = $field;
  }
  foreach ($qoperator as $operator1) {
   $this -> operator = $operator1;

  }
  foreach ($values as $value1) {
   $this -> value = $value1;

  }

  //if (in_array($operator, $operators)) {
  if (count($fields) === count($values)) {
   $sql = "SELECT " . implode(',', $keys) . "FROM {$table} WHERE" . implode('AND', '{$field} {$operator} ?');

  } elseif (count($fields) === 0) {
   $sql = "SELECT " . implode(',', $keys) . "FROM {$table} WHERE" . implode('AND', '{$field} {$operator} ?');

  }
  if (!$this -> query($sql, array($value)) -> error()) {
   return $this;
  }

  //}

  return false;
 }

 public function select($keys, $table, $where) {

  return $this -> getf($keys, $table, $where);
 }

 public function insert($table, $fields = array()) {
  $keys = array_keys($fields);
  $values = '';
  $x = 1;
  foreach ($fields as $field) {
   $values .= '?';
   if ($x < count($fields)) {
    $values .= ', ';
   }
   $x++;
  }

  $sql = "INSERT INTO {$table} (" . implode(',', $keys) . ") VALUES ({$values})";
  if (!$this -> query($sql, $fields) -> error()) {
   return true;

  }
  return false;
 }

 public function update($table, $id, $fields) {
  $set = '';
  $x = 1;

  foreach ($fields as $name => $value) {
   $set .= "{$name} = ?";
   if ($x < count($fields)) {
    $set .= ', ';
   }
   $x++;
  }
  $sql = "UPDATE {$table} SET {$set} WHERE TENDER_ID = {$id}";
  
  if (!$this -> query($sql, $fields) -> error()) {
   return true;
  }
  return false;
 }

 public function results() {
  return $this -> _results;
 }

 public function first() {
  //return $this->results()[0];
  return current($this -> results());
 }

 public function error() {
  return $this -> _error;
 }

 public function count() {
  return $this -> _count;
 }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than setting $user and adding a new connection whenever the user changes, you can store the connections and only make a new connection when it doesn't exist:

```
private function __construct($user) {
    try {
        $this->_pdo = new PDO(
            'oci:dbname=//'.Config::get($user.'/host').'/'.Config::get($user.'/db'), 
            Config::get($user.'/username'), 
            Config::get($user.'/password')
        );
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die($e -> getMessage());
    }
}

public static function getInstance($user) {

    if (!empty(self::$_instance[$user])) {
        self::$_instance[$user] = new DB($user);
    }
    return self::$_instance[$user];
}
```

Comment: Dear jeffwa I am getting this error here "Using $this when not in object context in line  if ($user != $this->user || !isset(self::$_instance))"

Comment: yes this is working,but application is bit slow in comparison to when I use single user.

Comment: You're asking the application to change DB connections which adds overhead. Using multiple users to access the same DB just different tables isn't ideal (or really recommended.)

Comment: yes you are right but I can not change that. the five users may be treated as five different databases.   is there any way to pool these connections in DB class  for each user so that this switching is instantaneous.

Comment: I've edited my answer so that connections are pooled

Comment: Your answer seems correct to me but I am getting this error while using this code "Call to a member function query() on a non-object in line .....". May be we are real close but something is problematic. Please help once more if you can devote some time.

Comment: Now i am getting Undefined index: 'misc' in line no 33. 'misc' is the name of database user i am passing into db::getInstance('misc').I have initialized   $_instance=array();   It means it is not able to return  self::$_instance[$user].

Comment: The above solution was giving error as i  have pointed in comments, but I have figured something like this   will it solve connection pooling issue.Please give your valueable comments.                                                         public static function getInstance($conn) {

   if ($conn != self::$_user || !isset(self::$_instance)) {
   self::$_instance[$conn] = new DB($conn);
  }

  return self::$_instance[$conn];
 }
 will it resolve my connection pooling issue.